# Longtable problem

Tags: longtable, landscape

I am still struggling with my tables. My new problem is that I have a long table that should be split on more pages. I am trying to use the package longtable. The code I wrote so far is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs, makecell, siunitx}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[referable,para]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[scale=.75]{geometry}
\captionsetup{font=bf}
\setlength{\textheight}{23.0cm}
\sisetup{group-separator={,}, table-format=1.3, table-space-text-post=***, table-number-alignment =center}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l*{8}{c}}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Baseline model \label{table3}}
\centering\small
\hline\hline
 &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(a)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(b)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(c)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(d)}\\
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Fst Stage}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Snd Stage}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Fst Stage}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Snd Stage}\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{9}{l}
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(a)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(b)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(c)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(d)}\\
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Fst Stage}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Snd Stage}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Fst Stage}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Snd Stage}\\
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{9}{l}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
\hline \hline
\begin{tablenotes}
\item [] abc
\end{table}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

However I receive the following error message

```
tab4_R.tex
20
Misplaced \noalign.
\caption ->\noalign 
                    \bgroup \@ifnextchar [{\egroup \LT@c@ption \@firstofone ...
l.20 \caption
             {Baseline model \label{table3}}
```

I cannot understand what is going wrong. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I get numerous errors with this. You might get better results from posting a working example. Stripping it down to a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) is of course the best.

Comment: `\end{table}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{longtable}`  you can not have either `table` or `threeparttable` _inside_ `longtable`  have you seen any documentation suggesting that should work? If so please give a link and we'll try to get the author to fix it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes you are right. \end{table} should not be there. Anyway even if I drop it, I still cannot have a longtable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use only environment `longtable` it can have footnotes, if really needed. And it can be inside \begin{landscape} ... \end{landscape} for very wide tabulars. Needs package pdflscape.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs, makecell, siunitx}
\captionsetup{font=bf}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=.75,textheight=23cm]{geometry}
\sisetup{group-separator={,}, table-format=1.3, table-space-text-post=***, 
table-number-alignment =center}
\begin{document}
    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
    \begin{longtable}{l*{8}{c}}
        \caption{Baseline model \label{table3}}\\\hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(a)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(b)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(c)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(d)}\\
            &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Fst Stage}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Snd 
            Stage}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Fst Stage}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Snd Stage}\\\hline
        \endfirsthead
            \hline
            &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(a)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(b)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(c)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{(d)}\\
            &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Fst Stage}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Snd 
                Stage}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Fst Stage}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Snd Stage}\\\hline
        \endhead
            \hline \multicolumn{9}{l}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
        \endfoot
            \hline\hline
        \endlastfoot
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
            SF                & 0.011*** \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001) &0.011*** 
            \\(0.001)&0.011*** \\(0.001)\\
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Herbert. The point is that I need to have a sideways table, as it is more good-looking. In addition, I should underline some elements in the headings.

Comment: no problem. Use the `longtable` inside `\begin{landscape} ... \end{landscape}`. Needs package `pdflscape`